# oracle null value in quotes - yet another newbie question

Tags: oracle, null

I have a where clause like

```
"and uc.completion_status in ('[P....]') "
```

here ('[P....]') is the user input from taken a dropdown list in the user interface. and dropdown list consists three options Y, N or NotStarted

not started is defined with nvl(uc.completion_status, 'NotStarted') therefore NotStarted is null actually. and null in quotes is not working. how can this problem can be handled?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean that when `uc.completion_status` is null then it should match the `NotStarted` value which came from UI ? where does the `'null'` (null in quotes) come from ?

Comment: NotStarted comes from ui but since i have set this value with nvl(uc.completion_Status, 'NotStarted'), when NotStarted selected, the query returns nothing,

Comment: if i wouldnt set NotStarted and then null value listed in the dropdown, null value will be in quotes

Comment: Am I correct: When you created the list you set null to be 'NotStarted', so now you can get 'Y','N' and 'NotStarted'. When you query afterwards you have in your where clause `uc.completion_status in (<the list that might contain 'Y','N' and 'NotStarted'>)` so when uc.completion_status was null you fing no records, right?

Comment: yen you are right

Answer (score 2):

Simple! Put `NULL` without quotes.

E.g.

```
INSERT INTO tableName (columnName1, columnName2) VALUES ('Value1', NULL)
```

We must always use `NULL` without quotes when we intend to use NULL values. Putting quotes around it, like `'NULL'` makes it a string literal and it is treated as character data. Hence for using NULL values, we must always use `NULL` without quotes, be it a null string, a null number or a null BLOB. For every data type, we must use `NULL` without quotes.

Comment: when change where clause like  where and uc.completion_status in ([P....]) then other Y and N values will be without qoutes too.

Comment: @elimerv, then why not `nvl(uc.completion_status, 'null') in ([P...])` ? (unless you have an index on completion_status and you don't want to use a function)

Comment: to clarify my problem; <pre><code> select myTasks, nvl(uc.completion_status, 'NotStarted') from myTable where uc.completion_status in ('[SelectedParameterByEndUser]')<code><pre> i have some tasks with statuses completed(stores as Y in DB), not completed(stored as N in DB), and Not Started (stored as null in DB) and when i select N or Y, query return ok but when i select null(or notStarted by defining it with nvl ) nothing returns. actually i dont want to display  a null thing on the ui

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care for an index on the `uc.completion_status`, then you simply need to do:

```
select ...
from ...
where ... and nvl(uc.completion_status, 'NotStarted') in (<the list>)
```

Otherwise, you can create a [function based index](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10471/adfns_indexes.htm#i1006366) (as @LeighRiffel commented)

Comment: Thank you man! i have try to try this but some other mistake prevent me from the solutipon

Comment: Neither of these would use an index on `uc.completion_status`.  A function based index would work for the first query, see http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/201c9/2

Comment: Thanks @LeighRiffel, as for the first query that's obvious, but I wonder if the second one will *never* use the index... anyway since the second one is wrong (as `<the list>` will not be a string in runtime) I'll update my answer

Comment: Correct, it will *never* use an index on completion_status because there is a function on it.

Comment: Thanks @LeighRiffel, but I meant the [second query](http://dba.stackexchange.com/revisions/36596/1) which I've removed, there is no function on the column, though there is a 'IS NULL' so according to [this](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:2458637000346464034) AskTom post it should depend on other keys of the index

Comment: Yes, I understood which query you meant and I see what you are trying to say - An index on completion_status alone will not be used in a query specifying `completion_status IS NULL` but as Kyte points out, if a NULLable value is in an index with a value that cannot be NULL, then that index may be used.  e.g. (completion_status, 0)  This is indeed another way to index NULL values.